# Why are OPTIONS requests not arriving in my ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, http-verbs

I can't seem to receive HTTP `OPTIONS` requests in my IIS6 hosted ASP.NET application. I'm testing it using a debug breakpoint (and file-log) in my `Global.asax`'s `Application_BeginRequest` method. The breakpoint is never hit and the client gets a HTTP 403 Forbidden, I'm assuming from IIS6 directly (`GET`s and `POST`s work fine btw).

I've tried several things in the `web.config`, including adding the following line to either and both the `<system.webServer><handlers>` and `<system.web><httpHandlers>` sections.

```
<add name="OptionsHandler" verb="OPTIONS" path="*" type="System.Web.DefaultHttpHandler"/>
```

I've also played with the `<system.webServer><security><requestFiltering><verbs>` settings and `allowUnlisted="true"` and `<add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="true"/>`.

Also, I'm not using URLScan or any other tools that might intercept the calls. In case you're interested in IISLogs:

```
2011-07-11 20:26:05 W3SVC1215124377 127.0.0.1 OPTIONS /test.aspx - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+5.2;+rv:5.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/5.0 403 1 0
```

**Is there a way to receive `OPTIONS` request in an ASP.NET Application?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For IIS6, you will have to enable the OPTIONS verb explicitly in the management console, and you will also need to map it to be handlded by ASP .NET. Only then, you will be able to register your handler in `<system.web>` and get the request processed by ASP .NET.

(Note, `<system.webServer>` settings only applies to IIS7).

Comment: Found it! You have to explicitly allow the verb for each mapping in Web -> Properties -> Home Directory -> Configuration... -> Mappings. THX

Comment: For MVC you might need to do some more configurations: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/