# Magento: add product to cart by ajax request from external site

Tags: php, ajax, magento

I need to add product to magento cart from another site. I make ajax request to magento function with code

```
    $product_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);    
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => 1));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

New row appears in table sales_flat_quote, but when I open magento site - cart is empty. Why is that? What should I change in code to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Thanks to this [Cross domain jQuery ajax call with credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954080/cross-domain-jquery-ajax-call-with-credentials) question.
All I need is add

```
  xhrFields: {
     withCredentials: true
  }
```

for my ajax request in js script and

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true");
```

in php code.