# Angular app running on azure app service not receive .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie sent by .net core web api app on azure

Tags: angular, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular-fullstack

I have angular 5 app and .net core 2.0 web api app hosted on azure as app services.
Apps have two urls as below.

angularclient.azurewebsites.net
serviceapi.azurewebsites.net

The issue I am facing is angular app not receiving .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie that is sent by serviceapi. Http post request generated by angular app has "withCredentials: true" header. I have defined cors policy in service API as below.

```
      app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("angularclient.azurewebsites.net").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());
```

I have sent a request using POSTMAN and test if cookies are sent by the server. For the POSTMAN request cookies are receiving without any issue. 
When I host the apps in my test IIS server and check. On that environment application working fine. Help me to find a solution to this issue.

Comment: You say you have a problem with Anti-forgery cookie not being set, but you showed us the code for configuring cors. Angular expects a specific header name so.. you need to configure your aspnet core app correctly. See [here](https://damienbod.com/2017/05/09/anti-forgery-validation-with-asp-net-core-mvc-and-angular/) and [here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClientXsrfModule)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have already configured my .net core app as you mentioned. Below are my .net core configurations

`services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");`

`app.UseAntiforgeryTokenMiddleware("X-XSRF-TOKEN");`

In application middleware configuration as below

     `context.Response.Cookies.Append(requestTokenCookieName, tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
                    {
                        HttpOnly = false
                    });`

Comment: Can you post your entire `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` methods here? If it's too long, hide the not related parts. Configuring CORS has to happen before the call to `AddMvc`.

Comment: Ah also: `context.Response.Cookies.Append..` use this for the cookie name `XSRF-TOKEN`. This is the default cookie name angular will look for, not `X-XSRF-TOKEN` as you are passing.

Answer (score 0):

This takes a week to find a reason why this issue happened in azure app services. Reason was Microsoft has banned cookies on azurewebsites.net top domain by including it in public [suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/). You can find more details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300175/asp-net5-mvc-6-cookies-not-being-shared-across-sites)