# CORS Issue with Azure Ad Authentication Asp.net Core 2.2 and Angular 8.2 client

Tags: cors, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, angular8, asp.net-core-2.2

I am setting up a new ASP.NET Core Web API with Work Or School Account Authentication. This API will be consumed by an Angular 8.2 application. I added CORS (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors - version 2.2.0) from Nuget and configured my Startup.cs file to AddCors and UseCors. I have configured as AllowAnyOrigin, AllowAnyMethod, AllowAnyHeader. My UseCors statement is above UseMVC statement too.

The API works fine when executed independently on web browser. However, when I plug this into the Angular App, I am getting below error.

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44342/api/Values' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Why is AllowAnyOrigin is not being recognised?

Can someone help me?

Comment: What’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Answer (score 1):

Below piece of code worked charm for me:

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
       if (env.IsDevelopment())
       {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
       }

```
  app.UseAuthentication();

  app.UseCors(builder => builder
  .AllowAnyOrigin()
  .AllowAnyMethod()
  .AllowCredentials()
  .AllowAnyHeader());
  app.UseMvc();
```

}

Which i found [here](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/02/28/using-openidconnect-with-azure-ad-angular5-and-webapi-core-webapi-configuration/).

There are several post around the similar issue , here is the link for the same, please check and let me know if it worked for you.

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

[Angular app running on azure app service not receive .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie sent by .net core web api app on azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759342/angular-app-running-on-azure-app-service-not-receive-aspnetcore-antiforgery-coo)

[ASP.NET5, MVC 6 Cookies not being shared across sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300175/asp-net5-mvc-6-cookies-not-being-shared-across-sites)

Hope it helps, feel free to tag me in any of your conversation.