# Cross origin request with CORS filter

Tags: ajax, angularjs, rest, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to make cross origin requests from an AngularJS 1.3 app to a REST service. Although I enabled CORS Filter, I get a 403 Forbidden response. Here's the request (copy paste from chrome dev tools). On IE 9 it appears to work. I get 403 error code on Chrome and Firefox.

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/<path>
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:403 Forbidden
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers:x-auth-token, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, ike Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Accept, x-auth-token, Content-Type,        
Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/plain
Date:Tue, 17 Feb 2015 07:11:24 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

The URL is ok. If I paste it into the browser directly it works.

The cross origin authentication works:

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request        
URL:http://localhost:8080/<serviceName>/webapi/authentication/authenticate
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en,ro;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en-GB;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:42
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:9000
Referer:http://localhost:9000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,     like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
{username: "user", password: "pass"}
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Content-Length:100
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 17 Feb 2015 07:11:24 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=805B2490C0BA258D7D0FF4235BA49B76; Path=/<appcontext>/;     
HttpOnly
```

I'm using Spring Security for authentication. What else do I need for cross origin requests?

CORS filter used:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CORSFilter2 implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse     servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:9000");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, x-auth-token, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By CORS non-`GET` requests send preflight request in browser automatically. You should allow `OPTIONS` method on your HTTP server and in the CORS allow headers to serve these requests. Your server should respond with CORS allow headers and `200 ok` with empty response body to the preflights.

According to your comments the problem is probably caused by your custom `x-auth-token` header, which is not sent by the `OPTIONS` request, so your server responded with `403 forbidden`.

> A preflight call is a call to determine if an action is allowed. It
>   should not require credentials to determine if I can do something, it
>   should only require credentials to actually do it.

- [CORS preflight issues in Firefox and Chrome](http://community.bonitasoft.com/answers/cors-preflight-issues-firefox-and-chrome)

I agree with Ryan, you should not check auth headers by OPTIONS.

Comment: OPTIONS is already allowed: Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS. In the filter I have : response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, HEAD, OPTIONS"); In the response header it appears as allowed.

Comment: @MihaiSerban Is it enabled on the HTTP server (e.g. in htaccess/web.config)? Do you handle it with 200 ok?

Comment: The CORS filter is enabled in web.xml, that's why the headers appear in the response. And it's mapped to the url-patterns used.

Comment: @MihaiSerban I think you misunderstood. This has nothing to do with CORS headers. The problem that your server does not serve the OPTIONS request. You should add it to the route and send 200 ok with empty response body and ofc. the same CORS allow headers. Btw. this problem has nothing to do with rest and angular.

Comment: You were right, I missunderstood. I have this @OPTIONS
 @Path("/resource")
 public Response getOptions() {
  return Response.ok().build();
 }    configured in the REST endpoint but it never enters the method.

Comment: Also, I tested now on IE 9 and the requests work there. I have the 403 forbidden only in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @MihaiSerban Afaik CORS support is from MSIE10. By firefox test the OPTIONS call with: https://addons.mozilla.org/hu/firefox/addon/restclient/ . OPTIONS is called only before PUT and DELETE from the browser, afaik GET and POST does not send preflight. By your `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` you should allow PUT and DELETE if you want to support them in your API.

Comment: @MihaiSerban Hmm interesting, do you have this problem by trying to send a POST?

Comment: I just checked. I was wrong, it can send preflight by POST as well. Check the chrome console afaik. it has better error messages by CORS than firefox. Btw. I had a similar issue 2 years ago: https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2542

Comment: @MihaiSerban Your case is clearly a server configuration issue. Probably it is not allowed in the server config to serve OPTIONS or you don't handle OPTIONS requests well by your HTTP framework. CORS is a client side thing, it won't cause 403 forbidden, that's a server error by serving the OPTIONS HTTP request... Here is a similar issue than yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151096/cors-preflight-request-returning-403-forbidden-subsequent-request-then-only-s

Comment: @MihaiSerban 
In your case probably the x-auth-token is not sent with the OPTIONS request and that's why you get 403. Try to use Authorization instead. Or try to log the OPTIONS requests and check whether the x-auth header is sent.

Comment: Thanks for this info. From chrome REST client I can send an OPTION request which gets to the backend. But the OPTIONS that the browser is sending never get to that point. Maybe the authentication header.

Comment: @MihaiSerban Try to use Authorization header instead of x-auth-token.

Comment: @MihaiSerban Btw, you can check by turning of authorization on the server. If it gets through, then that is the problem...

Comment: I managed to fix this by removing the x-auth-token. This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of preflighted CORS requests, you need to be aware that credentials aren't sent in the `OPTIONS` request. If the latter sends back the correct CORS headers in its response, the target request is then called with the credentials. That's why you have the 403 status code...

So you need to tweak your CORS filter not to try to authenticate this `OPTIONS` request.

In addition to the previous answer, this link could help you to solve your problem: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/11/12/understanding-and-using-cors/.

Comment: Yes, I definitely agree with you. I'll have a look at my very old answer to fix that... Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: Please also don't put taglines in posts.  SE does discourage it, and it doesn't add anything to the post.